# StreamCorruptedException on only two out of three boxes?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, stream, ehcache

I'm completely at a loss as to why this is occurring.  I have a javascript file deployed to three test boxes.  On two of them, I get the following error when I hit the page (below).  As you can see, it says the stream header is a string of zeroes, and there are no zeroes in the file it's reading.  I assume this means that it's trying to read the data but nothing's coming through (hence all the unset bits...) but the fact that it works on one box but not the other two is baffling, since they all have the same code deployed to them.

I've looked through the Java service for any streams that aren't closed or read properly, but the service doesn't even open them.  As you can see in the stack trace, it utilizes `Ehcache` which performs those operations (and are implemented correctly).

Any pointers in the right direction on what in the world this is doing?

```
exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page/CacheHistory.jsp at line 6

3: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
4: 
5: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
6: <jsp:useBean id="cacheHistory" class="org.jpg.CacheHistory" />
7: <html> 
8: <head>
9:  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:519)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:428)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
    net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.retrieve(DiskStorageFactory.java:964)
    net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment.decodeHit(Segment.java:178)
    net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment.get(Segment.java:216)
    net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.get(DiskStore.java:504)
    net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.getQuiet(DiskStore.java:511)
    net.sf.ehcache.store.FrontEndCacheTier.getQuiet(FrontEndCacheTier.java:196)
    net.sf.ehcache.Cache.searchInStoreWithoutStats(Cache.java:2101)
    net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1630)
    net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1597)

root cause

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    net.sf.ehcache.util.PreferTCCLObjectInputStream.<init>(PreferTCCLObjectInputStream.java:39)
    net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.read(DiskStorageFactory.java:375)
    net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.retrieve(DiskStorageFactory.java:960)
    net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment.decodeHit(Segment.java:178)
    net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment.get(Segment.java:216)
    net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.get(DiskStore.java:504)
    net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.getQuiet(DiskStore.java:511)
    net.sf.ehcache.store.FrontEndCacheTier.getQuiet(FrontEndCacheTier.java:196)
    net.sf.ehcache.Cache.searchInStoreWithoutStats(Cache.java:2101)
    net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1630)
    net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1597)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file being read is corrupt on the platforms that fail.

Comment: I've gone on and opened up the files in VIM on the boxes, and everything looks exactly the same as the file that doesn't fail.  Is this an indicator that the file isn't actually corrupt?  Or does that not matter?